# C# and C++ socket data encryption

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, encryption

Im writing a C# client and C++ server which should communicate via TCP sockets with no encryption. Everything is great. However I need to encrypt some of the data (but not all of it) like login information. I am looking for a asymmetric algorhythm to implement on the C# and C++ side to implement secured exchange of login data. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`RSACryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

Comment: I assumed he is working with .NET, the class is there also for C++.

Answer (score 0):

[RSA on Wikipeida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29)

There are a few ready made implementations both for c# and c++.

[C# implementation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx)

[C++ implementation](http://www.efgh.com/software/rsa.htm)